# Do attacks in Pokemon Go have added effects?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am too low-level to challenge gyms, but I have caught some Pokemon with moves such as Struggle and Poison Sting, which have added effects in the core games (dealing some damage to the user, and chance to poison, respectively).

Do these attacks do anything except deal damage in this game? I would not want to go into a battle and accidentally kill myself by using Struggle too much, and it would be great to afflict my enemies with debuffs.

Comment: Great question. I'm not even sure how to use different moves in a battle yet.

Comment: @GarrettJ Each Pokemon has two moves (shown on its profile page - these will vary even within the same species!). The first one is a basic attack, which you use in battle by tapping very fast. This charges up a blue bar which lets you use the second attack by pressing and holding.

Answer (score 1):

Attacks deal damage, are affected by type weakness/resistances (I'm not sure if [STAB](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Same-type_attack_bonus) is factored in the damage formula) and may inclict status conditions.

Each Pokemon has two moves. The first is a basic attack and the second is a special (more powerful) attack.

Battles work like this:

- Tap the screen to attack with your Pokemon's basic attack;
- Swipe left or right to dodge before your opponent's attack hits;
- Once you've filled up some of the blue meter below your Pokemon's health bar by attacking normally, you can unleash a more powerful attack by holding down on the screen before releasing.

Here is an image showing the blue bar:

[image: top of battle screen]

So if you have a special attack with 3 blue bars (you can check this in the pokemon status screen, where you can also see the listing of attacks it can perform) you would need to attack with the basic attack to fill up 3 blue bars (the ones below the green health bar in the image).

Sources: personal experience and [this wiki page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Gym_Battles)

Comment: This might be something that was recently added but I now have evidence this answer is incorrect.

Comment: I edited my answer to add status conditions. But that is not a recoil effect like the one from struggle. Those are not in the game.

Answer (score 0):

If the move has the blue bar broken up into separate section then you only need to fill a piece of that section to use the move

Comment: It seems as though you need to fill the whole bar, then you can use the move as many times as you have bars. I had a Raticate with dig, and could only use it once all 3 bars were full. From there, I could hold down to use Dig 3 times in a row.