# Are there skills other than attack type in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Does pokemon go have non-attack skills?

I am new to pokemon series, but from what I learned looking at the pokedex different pokemon should have skills, such as heals, temporary immunity to damage, buff/debuff etc.

I looked through my Pokemon at this point and I do have a few skills that SHOULD have side-effects such as debuffs at very least (for instance "Confusion" and other Psychic abilities). Even so, looking at the damage (being same as "normal" attacks), I don't think it's likely.

**I was wondering of if any of those non-damage skills are in game? 
If it has been announced, will there be any in the future?**

I am thinking the massive amount of pokemon to choose from might still end up producing REALLY shallow combat if direct attacks is all there is to it.

Edit:
Just to clarify, I am wondering about **non-direct-damage** skills and effects. For instance: Paralysis, Confusion, Speedup, Attack/Defense reduction, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do attacks in Pokemon Go have added effects?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273069/do-attacks-in-pokemon-go-have-added-effects)

Comment: The only effect I've seen is sometimes pokemon getting poisoned through Poison Fang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. I have spammed moves that should cause speed lowering [(mud bomb/mud shot)](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/mud-shot-move.html) confusion [(psybeam)](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/psybeam-move.html), paralysis, it never happened. Another thing to notice is that the "pokemon go database" doesn't even mention such things:[confusion](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/confusion-move.html)-the move, not the effect- for example, says nothing about the associated effect. Or that moves that rely heavily on such effects such as confuse ray, dynamic punch are not even in the game.

I have lvl 17 in pokemon go and fought quite alot with of those moves on my top pokemon.

I'd say it's safe to assume there's no such thing.

Even Magikarp's splash is just a damage spam move xD

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check out all the information. The link goes to line 261 where the different moves are listed
https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884#file-pokemon-go-data-dump-txt-L261

Also, this question is regardin second effects like poison or fire
[Do attacks in Pokemon Go have added effects?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273069/do-attacks-in-pokemon-go-have-added-effects)

Comment: Doesn't necessarily mean that it's used in the game.

Comment: yeah, like the appearance of Mewtwo and other legendary pokemon but, if not implemented yet, possible it wil

Comment: I do mean secondary effects, but non-damage type ones. Such as paralyze, confusion, reduced defense, etc.

Comment: and i do mean that all the information is there. if in the moves list ther is non of the above you say like paralyze ... is because is not implemented. about if its gonna be, we can only speculate.